# How to have mutliple methods of the same type? ("Processsing" programming)

Tags: java, methods, processing, draw

all.
I am newer to programming, but headstrong. 
I have an assignment for class, in which we have to use the "draw" method (which I understand is just a function, but in Java) and I need to leave a "trail". I already know how to leave a trail, but I want to leave a specific trail (mainly boot prints from my character's shoe). So I decided to write a separate draw method, but I can only use one. Is there any way to write another draw method?

If not, is there a way to leave a "trail" behind the man where I move him?

What I mean by trail: Using the draw method, I create a box that moves with my mouse. The draw command loops over and over, many times a second. However, it doesn't erase the previous draw, so a trail of boxes a left as they are draw out. I just want to have a trail of a specific shape, one that I can define.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your question is a little abstract. Can you post some code?

Comment: Please post your "2 methods" and maybe we will be able to make it into one

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

**Option 1:** Simply don't clear out old frames, by not calling the `background()` function every time `draw()` is called. This will cause your old drawings to stick around, which will look like a trail. This will work for simple stuff like circles, but will not work if you want your trail to be different from your drawing, or to do something like fade out over time.

**Option 2:** Store your trail in some kind of data structure. You might use an `ArrayList` that contains `PVector` instances, for example. Then each frame, clear out the old frames by calling `background()`, and then iterate over the data structure to draw your trail. Then add and remove from that data structure to change the trail over time.

**Option 3:** Draw your trail to an offscreen buffer. Hint: look up the `createGraphics()` function in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). This is similar to what you were trying to do, but instead of having a second `draw()` function you would draw the trail to the buffer. Then each frame, you would draw the buffer to the screen, and finally draw the object to the screen.

Comment: Amazing! I guess its not as simple as using a second draw method? I am not familiar with arrays...

Comment: @BrentonK No, it's not as simple as using a second `draw()` method. I see what you were trying to do though. See the third option that I just added to my answer, I think that's closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: You can also give the background some alpha for a quick and easy trail effect, e.g,  `background(50, 100)`. It will achieve the effect of fade out over time

Comment: @MasterYushi That will not always cause the trail to completely fade over time. It depends on the exact colors used for both the trail and the background.